# How do you programmatically delete a field?

Tags: 8, entities

I found this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/2012896 which lists this:

```
// Deleting field storage.
FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('entity_type', 'field_name')->delete();

// Deleting field.
FieldConfig::loadByName('entity_type', 'bundle', 'field_name')->delete();
```

but, of course, I get:  Fatal error: Class 'FieldStorageConfig' not found.

Any hints as to how this gets used?

Comment: I dont understand the negative rating

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Drupal 8 is using [object-oriented programming](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/getting-started-background-prerequisites-drupal-8) (except for some procedural bootstrapping files and the `*.module` and `*.theme` files).

When trying to access static methods of a class without a namespace, the class is expected to reside within the same namespace of the file you use the class name with.

This is not true for classes provided by Drupal core or other modules, when you use them within your own module.

So you have to properly use namespaces. When checking the [API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.4.x) for example for [FieldStorageConfig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21Entity%21FieldStorageConfig.php/class/FieldStorageConfig/8.4.x) and scroll a little down, you will find the correct namespace of this class. The same goes for the [FieldConfig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21Entity%21FieldConfig.php/class/FieldConfig/8.4.x) class.

So you could use both classes by altering your source code to:

```
// Deleting field storage.
\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('entity_type', 'field_name')->delete();

// Deleting field.
\Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::loadByName('entity_type', 'bundle', 'field_name')->delete();
```

However, it is best-practice to not prefix the class names by their full namespace, but use `use` directives at the top of your source code (after a possibly existing `namespace` declaration, if you are within the context of an own class).

This sums up to the following correct and working example:

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;

// Deleting field storage.
FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('entity_type', 'field_name')->delete();

// Deleting field.
FieldConfig::loadByName('entity_type', 'bundle', 'field_name')->delete();
```

PS.: When learning Drupal 8, it is always a good idea to check how other modules/core are doing it. You can search the code base for the class in question or use the [API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.4.x), which has a search function, and you may find plenty useful examples.

Comment: Note that since the field config has a dependency on the field storage it is only needed to execute `FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('entity_type', 'field_name')->delete();` and the field config will be deleted alongside it.

Comment: Following @pfrenssen's comment: you may want to invert the two instructions, so that field config is deleted before the field storage config, and you will remember what you have to do if you want to remove from a bundle but not from others.

Comment: Does this also delete the config dependency within the node/entity form/display modes? Or does that require additional steps?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @MarioSteinitz for your post. I just tried to enhance the snippet by check if the field exists before trying to delete it.

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
$field = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('entity_type', 'field_name');
if ($field) {
  // Delete this field.
  $field->delete();
}
else {
  // The field can not be loaded or maybe it does not exists.
}
```

Comment: How can i delete my custom table field using hook_uninstall?

Comment: A even more tested solution maybe : 
if ($fieldStorage && $fieldStorage->isDeletable()) {
   $fieldStorage->delete();
}

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to remove the field from all bundles, without specifying bundle name:

```php
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;

function remove_field(string $entity_type, string $field_id): void {
  $bundles = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo($entity_type);
  foreach ($bundles as $bundle) {
    if ($field_instance = FieldConfig::loadByName($entity_type, $bundle, $field_id)) {
      $field_instance->delete();
    }
  }

  if ($field_storage = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName($entity_type, $field_id)) {
    $field_storage->delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: There's really no nedd for that, just remove the field storage config and the field will be removed from all the bundles it is used in.